# Why RxJava2 doOnSubscribe run with confused order?

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

Following code print 1, 2

```
Observable.just(1)
    .doOnSubscribe(d -> System.out.println(1))
    .doOnSubscribe(d -> System.out.println(2))
    .blockingSubscribe();
```

And this print 2, 1

```
Observable.just(1)
    .doOnSubscribe(d -> System.out.println(1))
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .doOnSubscribe(d -> System.out.println(2))
    .blockingSubscribe();
```

In RxJava1, the two code both print "2, 1", because `doOnSubscribe` invoked before downstream subscribe to upstream.

In RxJava2, subscription happens from upstream to downstream (`Observer.onSubscribe`), but `doOnSubscribe` still invoked before subscription. So the confused order occured.

Even I can give a more confused situation:

```
Observable.just(1)
    .doOnSubscribe(d -> System.out.println(1))
    .doOnSubscribe(d -> System.out.println(2))
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .doOnSubscribe(d -> System.out.println(3))
    .doOnSubscribe(d -> System.out.println(4))
    .blockingSubscribe();
```

It print "3, 4, 1, 2" as my expected but not the most's expected.

Is this behavior by design? If yes, what's the benefit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`subscribeOn` starts a new subscribe chain on the specified thread but in order to support cancellation, it has to first call `onSubscribe` with a `Disposable` that can be cancelled early on - think about timing out an async source that is doing expensive preparation before it calls `onSubscribe`. In theory, it is also possible you get all sorts of interleaving between 3, 4 and 1, 2.

Comment: Yeah, I know why it happened. My question is why RxJava2 don't be like RxJava1 by invoking doOnSubscribe after subscribe downstream. So that we can get '4,3,2,1' which is more reasonable.

Comment: RxJava 1 didn't have `onSubscribe` and was limited to execute code when `subscribe` was called. RxJava 2's main goal was to fix the architectural and logical mistakes in v1 and being a full version bump, do it in a binary incompatible fashion.

Comment: Thank you sir. All I want it's you say this is by design or not. I will be careful to use `doOnSubscribe` and maybe custom an operator to do the actions by subscribe order.